# Execution failed for task ':rive_common:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'

Tags: flutter, rive

Unable to run the flutter application due to the following exception

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rive_common:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /home/toku/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.18.1/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /home/toku/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/rive_common-0.0.1/android/.cxx/Debug/2c2j2ru1/arm64-v8a rive_text}
  ninja: Entering directory `/home/toku/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/rive_common-0.0.1/android/.cxx/Debug/2c2j2ru1/arm64-v8a'
  [1/63] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rive_text.dir/home/toku/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/rive_common-0.0.1/ios/rive-cpp/src/rive_counter.cpp.o
  FAILED: CMakeFiles/rive_text.dir/home/toku/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/rive_common-0.0.1/ios/rive-cpp/src/rive_counter.cpp.o 
  In file included from /home/toku/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/rive_common-0.0.1/ios/rive-cpp/src/rive_counter.cpp:5:
  In file included from ../../../../../ios/rive-cpp/include/rive/rive_counter.hpp:8:
  In file included from ../../../../../ios/rive-cpp/include/rive/rive_types.hpp:59:
  /snap/flutter/current/usr/include/c++/9/memory:121:25: error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'uintptr_t' (aka 'unsigned int') loses information
    const auto __intptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(__ptr);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm using
flutter version 3.3.10,
rive: ^0.10.0,

I've done
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70149507/flutter-build-failed-for-android-bitmapexternalnativebuilddebug

Comment: I am also facing this when I installed flutter with the help of FVM in windows, does anyone have a solution for that ??

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
rive: ^0.9.1
```

this is the most stable rive package version

Answer (score 1):

## Answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77191340/7186671

## Error While Run Project

Execution failed for task ':rive_common:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

> [CXX1405] error when building with cmake using C:\Users\abdo\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\rive_common-0.2.7\android\CMakeLists.txt: C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:

## Fixed

1. remove this plugin "https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_dialog"

```
 awesome_dialog: ^3.1.0
```

or

2. Fixed Use Old Dependence:

```
  awesome_dialog: ^2.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. It seems i downloaded flutter from snap. So i deleted from snap and reinstalled manually, then this problem fixed. I didn't used any rive package in flutter app

You can check this out on [github:](https://github.com/rive-app/rive-flutter/issues/323#issuecomment-1638880701)

Answer (score 0):

We had this same problem and after some time we found out that the problem was in the project directory. It contained a space which the charset changes to the % character. We removed the space and the problem was solved.

> user/source/main project

to

> user/source/main_project