# Execution failed for task ':rive_common:configureCMakeDebug

Tags: flutter

## Error While Run Project

```
Execution failed for task ':rive_common:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1405] error when building with cmake using C:\Users\abdo\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\rive_common-0.2.7\android\CMakeLists.txt: C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fixed

1. remove this plugin "https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_dialog"

```
 awesome_dialog: ^3.1.0
```

or

2. Fixed Use Old Dependence:

```
  awesome_dialog: ^2.2.1
```

```
 awesome_dialog: ^3.1.0
```